# Поиск сборки (алгоритм)

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Подскажите оптимальный способ поиска сборки. Например в папке лежит 1k сборок (*.dll) и нужно выбрать например две специальные сборки. Как нужно пометить (атрибуты? вроде медленно будет искать рефлекшеном)  специфические сборки, для быстрого поиска в другой программе?

Может есть какой то способ дописать что то в мета-таблцицы сборки что бы очень быстро можно было прочитать и понят эта та сборка, что нужно, или нет?

Comment: Может быть, воспользуетесь [MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/Dd460648%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), если нужно искать не сборки, а типы в них.

Comment: @Vlad, мне сначала нужно понять из какой сборки эти типы брать.. с помощью MEF можно идентифицировать нужную сборку?

Comment: Можно заставить MEF найти нужный тип в каталоге со сборками, например.

Comment: @Vlad, а сколько это времени займет? Понимаете, может быть ситуация такая: я не знаю типа изначально, тип помечен атрибутом, атрибут лежит в другой сборке, так вот с таким сценарием быть? С MEF не работал ни разу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) (доступна так же через NuGet) и использовать ее для [анализа сборок](https://web.archive.org/web/20200812065403/http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2014/01/24/use-mono.cecil-to-reflect-assembly-metadata-with-better-performance.aspx).

Для теста я взял почти все сборки из `GAC`, скопировал их, чтобы получилось ~1 тысяча сборок, добавил туда несколько экземпляров моих библиотек с искомым атрибутом и выполнил такой код:

```
var assemblys = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\dlls\\")
    .Select(AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly)
    .Where(assembly => assembly.CustomAttributes.Any(ca=> ca.AttributeType.Name == "MyCustomAttribute"))
    .ToList();
```

Результат он выдал через ~600 миллисекунд (мерил с помощью `Stopwatch`). Мне кажется, что этого может быть для Вас достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо, да похоже это то что мне нужно!

Comment: Точно, Cecil умеет читать информацию из сборок без их загрузки.

Answer (score 3):

Основная потеря скорости будет при загрузке сборки в домен. Дальнейший анализ сборки, по сравнению с ее загрузкой, дешев, так что там хоть атрибут вешайте, хоть что. Если пойдете по этому пути, не забудьте делать это в отдельном аппдомене, чтобы потом выгрузить ненужные сборки.

Что можно придумать без загрузки всех сборок в домен:

- Самым быстрым вариантом будет поиск сборки просто по имени.
- Подписать сборки определенным ключом. При поиске считывать ключ и сравнивать с нужным.
- Обозначить сборки фиктивной версией (например, 127.0.0.1). При поиске считывать версию.
- Попробовать дописать несколько байт в dll, закодировав в них свой
  маркер, не повредив при этом сборки. Дальше открывать сборки как байт
  стримы и считывать маркеры.

Comment: Первый вариант не подход так как имя не известно. Второй вариант выглядит привлекательно. Спасибо.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan обновил ответ, посмотрите остальные варианты.

Answer (score 2):

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой, и решил её для себя при помощи *статического* определения нужных библиотек.

То есть при компиляции/установке программы специальная утилита определяет, какие из сборок нужно загрузить, и складывает эти данные в специальное место (например, файл). Теперь основная программа должна просто прочитать этот файл и загрузить нужные сборки, без необходимости рантайм-тестирования.

При добавлении сборок в каталог (или удалении из него) должна автоматически запускаться та же утилита, которая будет обновлять список. Разрешать пользователю добавлять/убирать сборки руками не нужно.

---

С другой стороны, если вы пишете плагинную систему, возможно, вам нужно не изобретать велосипед, и воспользоваться [встроенным фреймворком `System.AddIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384241%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, подойдет ли данное решение для вашей задачи. Но смысл примерно в следующем:

Вам понадобится интерфейс, который описывает функциональность классов, которые будут загружаться из сборок:

```
public interface ISomeTypeInterface
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

После этого в сборках вы объявляете типы следующим образом:

```
[Export(typeof(ISomeTypeInterface))]
public class SomeType1 : ISomeTypeInterface
{
    public string Name { get { return "Hello, world!"; } }
}
```

Далее, в месте, где нужно это все собрать пишете:

```
class SomeClass
{
    [ImportMany]
    private ISomeTypeInterface[] SomeTypes { get; set; }
}

void ComposeParts()
{
    var someClass = new SomeClass();
    // Каталог, в котором нужно искать типы можно настраивать более тонко, используя других наследников ComposablePartCatalog или создавая своих
    using (var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("."))
    using (var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog))
    {
        container.ComposeParts(someClass);
    }

    foreach (var t in someClass.SomeTypes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
    }
}
```

Если вам подойдет такой алгоритм работы с типами, то я бы советовал использовать MEF. Не могу сказать о скорости работы. У нас не возникало необходимости ускорить этот механизм, хоть он и используется часто и густо.

Comment: спасибо, интересное решение, но пока мне решение **ApInvent** подходит лучше всего. Как по времени так и по необходимости что то менять с уже написанных сборках.